# Large double quotes: best way to add them

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, css

I'm trying to wrap text in some big nice double quotes. I looked at [this tutorial](http://www.webdesignerwall.com/tutorials/simple-double-quotes/), but seems a little more complicated than I thought it should be. My gut tells me someone here in SO knows a smarter way. I'm open to anything: CSS, or PHP or Javascript, or Jquery (but preferably not JS/Jquery)

Comment: That tutorial you linked is very simple, you won't get anything simpler.

Comment: It it simple, you're right, but it's not playing nice with some of the code I already have. The blockquote for example forces top and bottom padding that I don't need, and the images are not even showing up.

Comment: @Fred: Have you tried playing around with the `padding`/`text-indent` values?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The tutorial doesn't look too complicated to me—I think their method is quite a good one.
If you don't like specifying one of the background images in `:first-letter`, you could use CSS3's support for multiple background images:

```
blockquote {
    background: url("open-quote.gif") top left no-repeat,
            url("close-quote.gif") bottom right no-repeat;
    /* Other rules... */
}
```

...but this will only work in [some browsers](http://a.deveria.com/caniuse/#feat=multibackgrounds).

If I were you, I'd use the method described in the tutorial.

Answer (score 2):

I'd recommend following the method they suggest: just add some styling on a blockquote element to give it a background image of your large quotes.

If you wanted a pure CSS solution, you can use something like this:

```
blockquote:before, blockquote:after {
    content: '"';
    font-size: 400%;
}
```

Of course, you'll have to play with the line heights and margins to get it looking ok, but even then, it's not gonna work in IE.